# How To Fix Indy TIdTCPServer Freezing When Sending Text To TIdTCPClient?

Tags: indy10, c++builder-2010

Cannot send text from **TIdTCPServer** To **TIdTCPClient**, the server hanging (Not Responding), it just freezes when trying to send text to the client.

I Started Recently using Indy TIdTCPClient and TIdTCPServer, i have the client application working well when sending and receiving response from the server form,
then issue is from the server it doesn't send data, and when i try to send data like Indy creators provided in their Doc, it just freezes and then stops responding (crashes) :(, the weird thing is that the server sends back the response on Execute Event, and not sending data with my send function, so here is my code that i use:

Server Execute Event:

```
void __fastcall TServerMain::IdTCPServer1Execute(TIdContext *AContext)
{
   UnicodeString uMessage;

   uMessage      = AContext->Connection->IOHandler->ReadLn();
   MessageDisplay1->Lines->Add(uMessage);
   AContext->Connection->IOHandler->WriteLn("Response OK!"); // i can receive the response from the client
}
```

Server Send Function:

```
void TServerMain::itsSendMessage(TIdTCPServer *itsName, UnicodeString uMessage) {
   TIdContextList *Clients;
   TIdContext *icContext;
   if ( uMessage.Length() != 0 && itsName->Active ) {
     Clients = itsName->Contexts->LockList();
     for (int i = 0; i < Clients->Count; i++) {
        icContext = (TIdContext*)Clients->Items[i];
        icContext->Connection->IOHandler->WriteLn(uMessage);
     }
   itsName->Contexts->UnlockList();
   }
 } // this function doesn't send text to the clients however, it just hangs the application for ever.
```

***Additional Note:*** The TIdTCPServer stops sending text even from it's `OnExecute` event when a client is disconnects!

**UPDATE:**

```
void __fastcall TMyContext::AddToQueue(TStream *AStream)
{
    TStringList *queue = this->FQueue->Lock();
    try {
        queue->AddObject("", AStream);
        this->FMessageInQueue = true;
    }
    __finally
    {
        this->FQueue->Unlock();
    }
}

void __fastcall TMyContext::CheckQueue()
{
    if ( !this->FMessageInQueue )
        return;

    std::unique_ptr<TStringList> temp(new TStringList);
    TStringList *queue = this->FQueue->Lock();
    try {
        temp->OwnsObjects = true;
        temp->Assign(queue);
        queue->Clear();
        this->FMessageInQueue = false;
    }
    __finally
    {
        this->FQueue->Unlock();
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < temp->Count; i++) {
        this->Connection->IOHandler->Write( static_cast<TStream*>(temp->Objects[i]), static_cast<TStream*>(temp->Objects[i])->Size, true );
    }
}
```

**Server Send Function:**

```
void __fastcall TServerMain::IdSendMessage(TIdTCPServer *IdTCPServer, TStream *AStream)
{
    if ( !IdTCPServer->Active )
        return;

    TIdContextList *Clients = IdTCPServer->Contexts->LockList();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < Clients->Count; i++) {
            static_cast<TMyContext*>(static_cast<TIdContext*>(Clients->Items[i]))->AddToQueue(AStream);
        }
    }
    __finally
    {
        IdTCPServer->Contexts->UnlockList();
    }
}
```

**Client Receive Function:**

```
void __fastcall TReadingThread::Receive() {
    TMemoryStream * ms = new TMemoryStream();
    this->IdTCPClient1->IOHandler->ReadStream(ms);
    ms->Position = 0;
    ClientMain->Image1->Picture->Bitmap->LoadFromStream(ms);
    delete ms;
}
```

This function is `Synchronized` in a `TThread`.

**This is how i send** a `TBitmap` using `TMemoryStream`:

```
void __fastcall TServerMain::CaptureDesktop()
{
    // Capture Desktop Canvas
    HDC hdcDesktop;
    TBitmap *bmpCapture    = new TBitmap();
    TMemoryStream *Stream  = new TMemoryStream();
    try {
        bmpCapture->Width  = Screen->Width;
        bmpCapture->Height = Screen->Height;
        hdcDesktop = GetDC(GetDesktopWindow());
        BitBlt(bmpCapture->Canvas->Handle, 0,0,Screen->Width, Screen->Height, hdcDesktop, 0,0, SRCCOPY);
        bmpCapture->SaveToStream(Stream);
        Stream->Position = 0;
        IdSendMessage(IdTCPServer1, Stream);
    }
    __finally
    {
        ReleaseDC(GetDesktopWindow(), hdcDesktop);
        delete bmpCapture;
        delete Stream;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TIdTCPServer` is a multi-threaded component, which you are not accounting for propery.

The server's various events are fired in the context of internal worker threads, not in the context the main UI thread.  Your `OnExecute` code is not syncing with the main UI thread when accessing `MessageDisplay1`, which can cause all kinds of problems, including but not limited to deadlocks.  You MUST sync with the main UI thread, such as with `TThread::Synchronize()` or `TThread::Queue()`.  For example:

```
void __fastcall TServerMain::IdTCPServer1Execute(TIdContext *AContext)
{
    String Message = AContext->Connection->IOHandler->ReadLn();

    // see http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/How_to_Handle_Delphi_Anonymous_Methods_in_C%2B%2B
    TThread::Queue(nullptr, [](){ MessageDisplay1->Lines->Add(Message); });

    AContext->Connection->IOHandler->WriteLn(_D("Response OK!"));
}
```

Also, you have 2 threads (whichever thread is calling `itsSendMessage()`, and the `OnExecute` thread) that are not syncing with each other, so they can *potentially* write text to the same client at the same time, overlapping each other's text and thus corrupting your communications.  When sending *unsolicited* messages from the server to a client, I *usually* recommend (depending on circumstances) that you queue the messages and let the client thread's `OnExecute` code decide when it is safe to send the queue.  Another reason to do this is to avoid deadlocks if one client becomes blocked, you don't want to block access to other clients.  Do as much per-client work in the client's own `OnExecute` event as you can.  For example:

```
class TMyContext : public TIdServerContext
{
private:
    TIdThreadSafeStringList *FQueue;
    bool FMsgInQueue;

public:
    __fastcall TMyContext(TIdTCPConnection *AConnection, TIdYarn *AYarn, TIdContextThreadList *AList = nullptr)
        : TIdServerContext(AConnection, AYarn, AList)
    {
        FQueue = new TIdThreadSafeStringList;
    }

    __fastcall ~TMyContext()
    {
        delete FQueue;
    }

    void AddToQueue(const String &Message)
    {
        TStringList *queue = FQueue->Lock();
        try
        {
            queue->Add(Message);
            FMsgInQueue = true;
        }
        __finally
        {
            FQueue->Unlock();
        }
    }

    void CheckQueue()
    {
        if (!FMsgInQueue)
            return;

        std::unique_ptr<TStringList> temp(new TStringList);

        TStringList *queue = FQueue->Lock();
        try
        {
            temp->Assign(queue);
            queue->Clear();
            FMsgInQueue = false;
        }
        __finally
        {
            FQueue->Unlock();
        }

        Connection->IOHandler->Write(temp.get());
    }

    bool HasPendingData()
    {
        TIdIOHandler *io = Connection->IOHandler;

        bool empty = io->InputBufferIsEmpty();
        if (empty)
        {
            io->CheckForDataOnSource(100);
            io->CheckForDisconnect();
            empty = io->InputBufferIsEmpty();
        }

        return !empty;
    }
};

__fastcall TServerMain::TServerMain(...)
{
    IdTCPServer1->ContextClass = __classid(TMyContext);
    ...
}

void __fastcall TServerMain::IdTCPServer1Execute(TIdContext *AContext)
{
    TMyContext *ctx = static_cast<TMyContext*>(AContext);

    ctx->CheckQueue();

    if (!ctx->HasPendingData())
        return;

    String Message = AContext->Connection->IOHandler->ReadLn();
    TThread::Queue(nullptr, [](){ MessageDisplay1->Lines->Add(Message); });
    AContext->Connection->IOHandler->WriteLn(_D("Response OK!"));
}

void TServerMain::itsSendMessage(TIdTCPServer *itsName, const String &Message)
{
    if ( Message.IsEmpty() || !itsName->Active )
        return;

    TIdContextList *Clients = itsName->Contexts->LockList();
    try
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Clients->Count; ++i)
        {
            static_cast<TMyContext*>(static_cast<TIdContext*>(Clients->Items[i]))->AddToQueue(Message);
        }
    }
    __finally
    {
        itsName->Contexts->UnlockList();
    }
}
```

Comment: I Already running reading thread `TReadingThread` for the `TIdTCPClient` to read `TIdTCPServer` messages all the time, the idea is, can i make a thread for `TIdTCPServer` as well and queue up messages (is it safe?).

Comment: @Abdennour how the client handles reading on its side has no relevance to how the server handles writing on its side. I already addressed the server side in my answer. `TIdTCPServer` already has its own threads, you need to learn how to work with them properly.

Comment: That was very helpful info, Thank you

Comment: Sorry but, how to send `TMemoryStream` or `TStream` from `TIdTCPServer`?, i want to send `TBitmap` to the `TIdTCPClient`.

Comment: @Abdennour my answer still stands. Simply update the queuing logic to accept `TStream` objects instead of strings, and then send the streams when extracting them from the queue. The `IOHandler` has a `Write(TStream)` overload, and there are `TIdThreadSafe(Object)List` classes available.

Comment: I'm getting an error in this line: `this->Connection->IOHandler->Write(temp.get());`

`Could not find a match for 'TIdIOHandler::Write(TList *)'`

Comment: @Abdennour because you are trying to send an entire list of objects in one go, which Indy doesn't support (it does support sending a list of strings). You will have to loop through the list manually sending each object individually.

Comment: Can you give me an example, because Indy is so complicated to me

Comment: @Abdennour looping through the items of a `TList` has nothing to do with Indy itself

Comment: @Abdennour, or, since you already have code to use a `TStringList` (in my answer above), you could just amend that code to use the `TStringList::Objects` property to carry your `TStream` objects, instead of switching the code use to `T(Object)List`. You would still have to loop through the `TStringList` manually to access the individual streams, though.

Comment: See **Update** above

Comment: @Abdennour `AddObject("", (TObject*)&AStream)` is wrong. Remove the `const` from `AStream` and use `AddObject("", AStream)` instead. As for the `Write()` error, you need to typecast the `TObject*` pointer you get from the list: `Write(static_cast<TStream*>(temp->Objects[i]))`. Also, you need to `delete` each `TStream` when you are done with it, unless you set the `TStringList::OwnObjects` property to true.

Comment: That however fixed the error issue, but it doesn't send the `TStream`, it gives no errors, also the client.

Comment: See **Server Send Function** and **Client Receive Function**

Comment: @Abdennour you can't transmit a single `TStream` to multiple clients at the same time, you will have to either serialize access to the `TStream` or else make a separate copy of the `TStream` data for each client. TCP is simply not designed for broadcasting, consider switching to UDP or Multicast instead. Also, in your reading thread, you need to sync with the main UI thread in order to access `Image1` safely