# How to Continuously send TBitmap from TIdTCPServer to TIdTCPClient using Indy Components?

Tags: c++builder

I know how to send a string from TIdTCPServer but i'm stuck on how to send TBitmap continuously to the TIdTCPClient, i use this code to send TStream:

```
void __fastcall TSystemMain::IdServerSendStream(TIdTCPServer *IdTCPServer, TStream *AStream)
{
    // Send To Client
    TIdContextList *Clients = IdTCPServer->Contexts->LockList();
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < Clients->Count; i++) {
            static_cast<TMyContext*>(static_cast<TIdContext*>(Clients->Items[i]))->Connection->IOHandler->Write(AStream);
        }
    } __finally
    {
        IdTCPServer->Contexts->UnlockList();
    }
}
```

It simple doesn't work for me.

Comment: Do you get any error messages that might be helpful? "It simple doesn't work for me" doesn't explain your problem well

Comment: This code doesn't send the stream as i expecting it to do, it does nothing (no errors), just nothing, the server sends the text normally and the client as well, but it doesn't send the `TBitmap`.

Comment: Well, for one thing, you are not sending the stream's size before sending its bytes, so the clients have no way of knowing how many bytes are actually being sent so they can read the bytes correctly. You should set the `AWriteByteCount` parameter of `TIdIOHandler.Write(TStream)` to true. It is false by default. And then make sure the clients read that size value before then reading the number of bytes specified (`TIdIOHandler.ReadStream()` does that by default).

Comment: This however sends the stream from `OnExecute` event only, not when i for EX: click a button to send, i have similar problem with sending text from `TIdTCPServer`, however this issue fixed when i made a class `TMyContext` derived from base class `TIdServerContext`, but still cannot send `TStream`. Also i have similar problem in [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54568243/how-to-fix-indy-tidtcpserver-freezing-when-sending-text-to-tidtcpclient/54581354?noredirect=1#comment96416485_54581354](How To Fix Indy TIdTCPServer Freezing When Sending Text To TIdTCPClient?
)